# Decoding a message with Huffman tree

Tags: java, huffman-code

When I send a string of bits to be decoded, it seems to require one additional bit to decode properly. I've printed out the tree in pre-order, and I've drawn the tree on paper to make sure I wasn't missing something. The pre-order and my drawn tree match, but the bits required to produce the correct letter is off.

```
public void decode(String code){
    String result = "";
    TreeNode current = root;
    current.preOrder();
    for(int i = 0;i < code.length();i++){
        //left--0
        if(Character.getNumericValue(code.charAt(i))==0){
            if(current.getLeft() == null){
                result += current.getWeight().getLetter();
                current = root;
                i--;
            }else
                current=current.getLeft();
        }
        //right--1
        else if(Character.getNumericValue(code.charAt(i))==1){
            if(current.getRight() == null){
                result += current.getWeight().getLetter();
                current = root;
                i--;
            }else
                current=current.getRight();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

My tree is building correctly every time which makes me believe the error is in the decoding method. However, I can't seem to figure out why it needs additional bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing how your nodes are laid out I can only guess. When traversing left/right you probably need to check if you've landed on a leaf node and emit its character if so.

```
if (current.getLeft() == null) {
    ...
}
else {
    current = current.getLeft();
    if (current.isLeaf()) {
        result += current.getWeight().getLetter();
        current = root;
    }
}
```

The same goes for the right side.

**Don't Repeat Yourself**

To avoid duplicating the two lines that append the character and reset the current node to the root four times, you could instead set a flag and check it at the end of the `for` block.

```
boolean append = false;
if (Character.getNumericValue(code.charAt(i)) == 0) {
    if (current.getLeft() == null) {
        append = true;
        i--;
    }
    else {
        current = current.getLeft();
        if (current.isLeaf()) {
            append = true;
        }
    }
}
// same for right side ...
if (append) {
    result += current.getWeight().getLetter();
    current = root;
}
```

**Other Tips**

- Switch from two `if` checks for `0` or `1` to a `switch` with a `default` that throws an `IllegalArgumentException`.
- Switch the `for` loop to a `while` to avoid pre-decrementing `i` just to have it incremented again and avoid stopping the loop.
- Start with `append` set to `true` since four out of six cases append.